# Posting to a webservice using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, asmx, httpurlconnection

How come I am only allowed to make posts to .com url's but not .asmx url's? Im a bit confused as what I want to generally do is send xml content to a .asmx url web service eventually. Can anyone supply me with tips why this doesn't work, and how I can post to a .asmx file?

```
public class POSTSenderExample {


    public String echoCuties(String query) throws IOException {
        // Encode the query
        String encodedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        // This is the data that is going to be send to itcuties.com via POST request
        // 'e' parameter contains data to echo
        String postData = "e=" + encodedQuery;


        URL url = new URL("http://echo.itgeeeks.asmx");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",  String.valueOf(postData.length()));

        // Write data
        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(postData.getBytes());

        // Read response
        StringBuilder responseSB = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            responseSB.append(line);

        // Close streams
        br.close();
        os.close();

        return responseSB.toString();

    }

    // Run this example
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.out.println(new POSTSenderExample().echoCuties("Hi there!"));

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `.asmx` isn't a top-level domain.

Comment: @GriffeyDog what do I need to do to post to a .asmx url, or send a string of data to a .asmx url? Any tips what to use or go along of doing it?

Comment: You need to know the proper URL for accessing whatever webservice you are trying to access. All I know is it won't take the form that your example shows.

Answer (score 0):

Using "POST" is correct.

Instead of calling 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
you have to call 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
(if you are using utf-8 encoding which is probably the case).

You also have to set the SOAP Action in the http- Header:
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", SOAPAction);
You can find the SOAP Action eihter in the wsdl- file. What I did to find out all expected Parameters: I used a working WS Client, and traced the TCP traffic in order to find out the expected HTTP headers.